# Atualizar controles em Custom Toolbox Control

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, controles, toolbox

Eu criei um projeto "Windows Forms Toolbox Control" e customizei alguns controles:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Criei uma galeria customizada para que todos os programadores da empresa possam instalar a toolbox e fazer uso dos controles:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Conforme a figura abaixo é possível ver a toolbox criada e disponível pra uso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu problema ocorre quando os controles sofrem algum tipo de alteração e precisam ser atualizados. Notei que após fazer o update da toolbox pela galeria do visual studio, os projetos que continham a referência da dll dos controles perdem a referência do local onde a dll estava.

A imagem abaixo mostra o caminho onde foi instalado a extensão:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após o update da toolbox o caminho foi alterado, veja na figura abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com isso os projetos ficam com o design quebrado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso atualizar esses controles de forma que os projetos não percam a referência?

Notei que existem algumas extensões instaladas não possuem essa nomenclatura diferente no diretório. É possível alterar a pasta de destino da extensão na instalação e na atualização?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

...desculpem pela quantidade de imagens, é que não encontrei uma forma melhor de expor o problema.

Answer (score 1):

No seu projeto, está definido as informações de Assembly? Está definido `Com Visible` para `True`? Está usando em seu projeto uma URI dinâmica ou constante? Testou em outros computadores? Já parou pra pensar que pode estar dando conflito entre as Namespaces do Sistema?

[image: Marque a caixinha]

Marque aquela caixinha `Make assembly COM-Visible` para True, daí os usuários poderão ter acesso geral aos "Tipos" e métodos do Projeto.

> Nota: Essa janela está localizada em **Project\Seu projeto -> Guia Application, no botão "Assembly Information".**

Não se pode definitivamente falar o que é o problema, irei testar aqui, se achar o que é o problema, te notifico.